# should multiple threads be spun up by kvm/virtio-scsi on the host during IO workload

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to pass-through a scsi lun to guest for best performance. What I am seeing on the host is that with iodepth=64 - 64 threads of qemu process are spun up for the VM. I believe this causes an excessive number of context switching and affects IO performance in guest.
Based on various papers and blogs my current configuration should be completely passing through the IO/disk. 
Are the new threads spun up on host a red herring? Or is something misconfigured?

Host: 
 CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
 Linux bb-smc-2 4.14.81-5.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 10 20:40:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Guest:
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
Linux icn-bb1-cmv 4.14.81-6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 16 19:29:25 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

...
`<iothreads>1</iothreads>`
...

```
<controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <driver queues='4' iothread='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
```

...

```
<disk type='block' device='lun' sgio='filtered' snapshot='no'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' error_policy='stop' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x60a010a0a976d6001962194c40c86ee6'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='sdc' bus='scsi'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
```

A sample fio command run from the host:
`fio --filename=/dev/sdc --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=64 --rw=randread --bs=4k --direct=1 --size=20G --numjobs=1`

```
  |-qemu-kvm -name guest=vm1,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-29-vm1/master-key.aes -machine pc-i440fx-rhel7.6.0,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off -cpu Skylake-Server-IBRS -m 4096 -realtime mlock=off -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 -object iothread,id=iothread1 -uuid e7b9aea0-564d-424b-bc87-9bb5375657f7 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=29,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay -no-hpet -no-shutdown -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x7 -device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x5 -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x1 -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x2 -device virtio-scsi-pci,iothread=iothread1,id=ua-788b1ea1-2f41-4e88-bbb8-7404c0418228,num_queues=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x9 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/config-vm1.iso,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -drive file=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x60a010a0a976d6001962194c40c86ee6,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-scsi0-0-0-0,werror=stop,rerror=stop,cache=none,aio=native -device scsi-block,bus=ua-788b1ea1-2f41-4e88-bbb8-7404c0418228.0,channel=0,scsi-id=0,lun=0,drive=drive-scsi0-0-0-0,id=scsi0-0-0-0 -netdev tap,fd=31,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=32 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:96:3e:93,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev socket,id=charchannel0,fd=33,server,nowait -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel1,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=2,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0,bus=usb.0,port=1 -spice port=5901,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on -device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
  |   `-75*[{qemu-kvm}]
```

notice 75 total threads for this VM. This will go down to 11 when fio is cancelled.

Full XML file:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='29'>
  <name>vm1</name>
  <uuid>e7b9aea0-564d-424b-bc87-9bb5375657f7</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <iothreads>1</iothreads>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.6.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>Skylake-Server-IBRS</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1.qcow2'/>
      <backingStore type='file' index='1'>
        <format type='qcow2'/>
        <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/cloud-centos-7.5.1804-kernel-4.14.81-6.qcow2'/>
        <backingStore/>
      </backingStore>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/config-vm1.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='lun' sgio='filtered' snapshot='no'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' error_policy='stop' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x60a010a0a976d6001962194c40c86ee6'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='sdc' bus='scsi'/>
      <alias name='scsi0-0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <driver queues='4' iothread='1'/>
      <alias name='ua-788b1ea1-2f41-4e88-bbb8-7404c0418228'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='direct'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:96:3e:93'/>
      <source network='macvtap-fe0' dev='fe0' mode='bridge'/>
      <target dev='macvtap0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/9'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/9'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/9'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-29-vm1/org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='connected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel1'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5901' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux' relabel='yes'>
    <label>system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c307,c525</label>
    <imagelabel>system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c307,c525</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+107:+107</label>
    <imagelabel>+107:+107</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 1):

A thread for each parallel I/O sounds normal for QEMU and doesn't sound like misconfiguration (I guess you can argue it's a red-herring in the sense it might trick you into thinking its something to worry about?). While your QEMU is generating request parallelism through threads it can be configured to use AIO (which won't need the threads for each simultaneous I/O) but be aware this can introduce its own issues... See https://lwn.net/Articles/671797/ for details.

Note: switching between threads of the same process is lower overhead than switching between entirely different processes so if you have the CPU and your numbers are close to what the host can do I wouldn't worry too much about trying to optimize it further.